Area of a sphere in discrete Euclidean space
In Verlinde's paper On the Origin of Gravity and the Laws of Newton (https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0785), he takes a sphere upon which an area of one $l_p^2$ represents one (classical) bit.
I suspect that there is a hidden assumption in his derivation; assuming information comes in discrete bits, there must be a smallest (holographic) sphere. I think that somehow he assumes space is discrete (even though using $A = 4\pi r^2$).
That got me thinking, what is the surface area of a sphere in a discrete Euclidean space in relation to its radius?
If the Planck length is the smallest length (which can be disputed), then it must pop up in this reasoning (or at least there would be a square for which $A = l_p^2$, being smaller than a 'bit-sized' area on the holographic screne, or Verlinde assumes some spacetime-geometry where this reasoning fails). Or perhaps there is no physical relation to spacetime and holography?
